# Python: how stop work from thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new with python and I am trying to made code that stop work in case timeout has been reached. But it seems that the tread correctly timeout but it does not stop the work.

Here is my code:

```
    import threading
    import time
    import sys

    def main():
        t1_stop= threading.Event()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1, args=(5, t1_stop))
        t1.setDaemon(False)
        t1.start()
        print 'thread 1 set'
        while True:
            print "blablabla"
            time.sleep(1)

    def thread1(time, stop_event):
        while(not stop_event.is_set()):
            #equivalent to time.sleep()
            print 'thread 1'
            stop_event.wait(time)

    main()
```

---

UPD
I update code using Timer instead of time.time.

- > ```
  > def main():
  >        stopped = threading.Event()
  >        timeout = 10
  >        #thread = threading.Thread(target=my_thread, args=(timeout, stopped))
  >        timer = Timer(timeout, my_thread(timeout,stopped))
  >        thread = threading.Thread((timer).start())
  >        thread.setDaemon(False)
  >        #thread.start()
  >        print 'thread 1 set'
  >        start_t = time.time()
  >        while thread.is_alive():
  >            print "doing my job"
  >            if not stopped.is_set():# and (time.time() - start_t) > timeout:
  >                stopped.set()
  >            #time.sleep(1)
  >
  >    def my_thread(time, stopped):
  >        while not stopped.wait(time): 
  >            print('thread stopped')
  >
  >    main()
  > ```

But I still get original problem the script does not stopped and continue.

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Timer` - is a thread. He execute function after timeout. Please, look [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

Comment: ok thanks. So in my case it is not possible to use it.

Answer (score 2):

you must call `t1_stop.set()` in main function for stop thread.

something like:

```
import threading
import time
import sys

def main():
    stopped = threading.Event()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=my_thread, args=(5, stopped))
    thread.setDaemon(False)
    thread.start()
    print 'thread 1 set'
    time.sleep(5) # +
    stopped.set() # +
    while True:
        print "blablabla"
        time.sleep(1)

def my_thread(time, stopped):
    while not stopped.wait(time): 
        print('thread 1')

main()
```

with 'blablabla':

```
def main():
    ...
    thread.start()
    print 'thread 1 set'
    start_t = time.time()
    while True:
        print "blablabla"
        if not stopped.is_set() and (time.time() - start_t) > 5:
            stopped.set()
        time.sleep(1)
```

UPD:

exiting from `while`:

```
    while thread.is_alive():
        print "blablabla"
        if not stopped.is_set() and (time.time() - start_t) > 5:
            stopped.set()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: For readability, rename variables. And you can use `.wait()`'s returned value instead of `.is_set()` (since Python 2.7): `while not stopped.wait(delay): print('thread 1')`

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. The thread is stopped but the while still continue. As timeout in thread has been reached I would like to stop the while.

Comment: Maybe the latest question (I hope): I get strange output: During script execution I get 'thread 1' --> that means my_thread def has been reached then I get a last 'blablabla' I do not understand why.

Comment: from the fact that timeouts are equal. you can change them and output change.